# Drupal 8: How to render every child page under the parent?

Tags: drupal-8

I would like to render all the subpages under top level page in Drupal 8. My site navigation has only top level pages and if they have any sub pages I would like to display them like a one pager where all of the pages are on a single view.

How to approach this? Can this be done in page.html.twig or do I need to make a custom module with some hooks to alter the page content?

So if the sitemap would be like this:

```
Fruits
   Banana
   Orange
   Grapes
Vegetables
   Potato
   Tomato
   Broccoli
Animals
   Dog
   Cat
   Goat
```

And the user would go to 'fruits' site render would be like:

```
Fruits
Banana
Orange
Grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create the three top level pages with the "subpages" as their content, you could still link to those "subpages" or areas with anchors. Then no trickery is needed with the rendering.

And what is the desired behavior if you click on "banana"? The same as if you clicked on Fruits, only scrolled to the banana section?

What are those pages exactly? Static content, a categorization (thus a collection of nodes or something), or something else?

Comment: I have quite a lot of content that can be be grouped under their own titles. Therefore it is easier to manage all this content if they are made as separate content and ordered in menu system.

"Banana" page would not have external link anywhere on the page, but if some user would find the banana page the whole fruits section should be rendered.

Content is mainly static, made with Paragraphs module.

Comment: Ok, have you tried to create a view? That would be like a normal category page or homepage, but instead of showing only teasers to the articles, you show the full articles.